# Sum of matrix elements Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I'm writing a method with 2 parameters, one int matrix and 1 int array. The method  must return the sum of the elements of a[][] having a multiple in the array b[].

Here is the method code

```
public static int sum(int[][] a, int[] b) {
    int matrixSum = 0;

    if (a != null && b != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                boolean multiple = false;
                boolean nullRow = false;
                if (a[i] == null || a[i].length < 1) {
                    nullRow= true;
                } else {
                    for (int k = 0; k < b.length && !multiple; k++) {
                        if (b[k] % a[i][j] == 0) {
                            matrixSum += a[i][j];
                            multiple = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return matrixSum;
}
```

This is the test class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = {{2, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}};
    int[][] a1 = {{2, 3}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}};
    int[][] a2 = {{2, 3, 4}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}};
    int[][] a3 = {{2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 1}};

    int[] b = {7, 8, 7, 20};


    System.out.println(sum(a, b)); // 15
    System.out.println(sum(a1, b)); // 11
    System.out.println(sum(a2, b)); // 14
    System.out.println(sum(a3, b)); // 11

}
```

In some cases it works in others no, some the result is incorrect and other times I receive OutBound error

Comment: Before we worry about the Java code, let's try to get the problem statement down first.  What does `having a multiple in the array` actually mean here, and can you give a simple 3x3 matrix example?

Comment: Have you learned how to use a debugger yet?

Comment: For this matrix int[][] a = {{2, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}} and this array int[] b = {7, 8, 7, 20} the multiples are 8 and 20 so the method must sum : 2+1+1+1+1+2+2+2

Comment: `sum : 2+1+1+1+1+2+2+2`  = 12 , not 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static int sum(int[][] a, int[] b) {

    if (a == null || b== null)  return 0;
    int matrixSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] == null || a[i].length <1 )     continue;
        for (int j = 0;  j < a[i].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < b.length ; k++) {
                if (b[k] % a[i][j] == 0) {
                    matrixSum += a[i][j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return matrixSum;
}
```

Using [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) can make it simpler and more concise:

```
public static int sum(int[][] a, int[] b) {

    return Stream.of(a).flatMapToInt( row -> IntStream.of(row)).
                 filter(i->isMultipleOf(i,b)).sum();
}

private static boolean isMultipleOf(int i, int[] b) {
    for(int j : b){
        if(j%i == 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem with IndexOutOfBounds lies in the line:

```
for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
```

You need to ask for the length of the second dimension, like:

for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work for this case : int[][] a1 = {{2, 3}, null, {2, 2, 2}};

Comment: I get NullPonterError

Answer (score 0):

This code works, thanks guys

```
public static int sum(int[][] a, int[] b) {
    int matrixSum = 0;

    if (a != null && b != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == null) {
                boolean nullRow = true;
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                    boolean multiple = false;
                    for (int k = 0; k < b.length && !multiple; k++) {
                        if (b[k] % a[i][j] == 0) {
                            matrixSum += a[i][j];
                            multiple = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return matrixSum;
}
```

Comment: `boolean nullRow = true;` is never used.